# JQ: how to delete object from array based on regex filter?

Tags: json, regex, jq

I have the following JSON array (simplified example):

```
[  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/cache"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/game_config"
  },
  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/use_replication"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/copy_replication"
  }
]
```

I want to remove from the array the objects that contain "replication". The result would be:

```
[  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/cache"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/game_config"
  }
]
```

I've found a way to get only them:

```
 .[] | select( .path | contains("replication"))
```

However I could not find a way to remove only them from my array, keeping all the other objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negation can be achieved using `not`.  In your case, since you mentioned using regular expressions, you could use `test/1` as follows:

```
map( select(.path | test("replication") | not))
```

Comment: Is | a pipe or a boolean-or?

Answer (score 2):

I've found another way to do it (I was missing the 'not' from the accepted answer):

```
 .[] | (select( .path | contains("value") | not ))
```

Comment: But `contains` is not a regex filter.  Also you asked for a technique that will remove items from an array, but .[] streams them.  Of course `[.[] | ...]` is equivalent to `map(...)` (by definition of `map`).

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself correctly. It doesn t matter if I remove or just filter them out, as long as the final result doesn't show the filtered out objects.

Comment: I didn't know the 'contains' is not a regex. Thank you!